# Go lang's equivalent of charCode() method of JavaScript

Tags: string, unicode, go

The `charCodeAt()` method in JavaScript returns the numeric Unicode value of the character at the given index, e.g.

```
"s".charCodeAt(0) // returns 115
```

How would I go by to get the numeric unicode value of the the same string/letter in Go?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The character type in Go is `rune` which is an alias for `int32` so it is already a number, just print it.

You still need a way to get the character at the specified position. Simplest way is to convert the `string` to a `[]rune` which you can index. To convert a `string` to runes, simply use the type conversion `[]rune("some string")`:

```
fmt.Println([]rune("s")[0])
```

Prints:

```
115
```

If you want it printed as a character, use the `%c` format string:

```
fmt.Println([]rune("absdef")[2])      // Also prints 115
fmt.Printf("%c", []rune("absdef")[2]) // Prints s
```

Also note that the `for range` on a `string` iterates over the runes of the string, so you can also use that. It is more efficient than converting the whole `string` to `[]rune`:

```
i := 0
for _, r := range "absdef" {
    if i == 2 {
        fmt.Println(r)
        break
    }
    i++
}
```

Note that the counter `i` must be a distinct counter, it cannot be the loop iteration variable, as the `for range` returns the byte position and not the `rune` index (which will be different if the `string` contains multi-byte characters in the UTF-8 representation).

Wrapping it into a function:

```
func charCodeAt(s string, n int) rune {
    i := 0
    for _, r := range s {
        if i == n {
            return r
        }
        i++
    }
    return 0
}
```

Try these on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/LPQbLXgFr9X).

Also note that `string`s in Go are stored in memory as a `[]byte` which is the UTF-8 encoded byte sequence of the text (read the blog post [Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](http://blog.golang.org/strings) for more info). If you have guarantees that the `string` uses characters whose code is less than 127, you can simply work with bytes. That is indexing a `string` in Go indexes its bytes, so for example `"s"[0]` is the byte value of `'s'` which is `115`.

```
fmt.Println("s"[0])      // Prints 115
fmt.Println("absdef"[2]) // Prints 115
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes...I am aware a string is treated automatically as an array of characters. JavaScript does this too.

Comment: @JheneKnights No, in Go a `string` is stored as a slice of `bytes` in memory, which is the `utf-8` encoded byte sequence of the characters. See this blog post for more details: [Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](http://blog.golang.org/strings). So obtaining `rune`s requires decoding the bytes.

Comment: The `charCodeAt` function returns the rune at the byte index `n`, not at rune index `n`.  See https://play.golang.org/p/QDLzyqSxkI

Answer (score 5):

Internally string is a 8 bit byte array in golang. So every byte will represent the ascii value.

```
str:="abc"
byteValue := str[0]
intValue := int(byteValue)
fmt.Println(byteValue)//97
fmt.Println(intValue)//97
```